# selector { text-align: "." right; }

Tags: text-align, decimal-point

I'm extremely new to coding so forgive if this is a basic question; however, I need a little direction and hope someone is able to provide an answer.

I'm reading an article pertaining to the alignment of numerical data to a decimal point within a table https://alistapart.com/article/web-typography-tables/#section6
which uses the below declaration for example:

```
td { text-align: "." center; }
```

Below is the basic table code I'm testing the syntax on.

```
<!-- HTML CODE -->
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <caption>
            October Expenses
          </caption>
          <colgroup>
            <col style="text-align: right" />
          </colgroup>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Expense</th>
              <th>Cost</th>
              <th>Payment Method</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td scope="col">01.10.21</td>
              <td scope="col">75" Samsung tv.</td>
              <td scope="col">$1,995.00</td>
              <td scope="col">Zip</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>07.10.21</td>
              <td>Netflix</td>
              <td>$15.99</td>
              <td>Debit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>12.10.21</td>
              <td>Paint Supplies</td>
              <td>$102.14</td>
              <td>Debit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>18.10.21</td>
              <td>Pencil</td>
              <td>$0.80</td>
              <td>Debit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2" style="text-align: right">Total</th>
              <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left">$2,113.93</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>

</html>

/* CSS */
    caption {
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 1%;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(n) {
      width: 20%;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #adc2a9;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #d3e4cd;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(1) {
      text-align: right;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(2) {
      text-align: left;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(3) {
      text-align: center;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(4) {
      text-align: left;
    }
    tbody td:nth-child(1) {
      text-align: right;
    }
    tbody td:nth-child(3) {
      text-align: center;
    }
    caption {
      font-size: 1.3rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    table,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 1%;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(n) {
      width: 20%;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #adc2a9;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #d3e4cd;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(1) {
      text-align: right;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(2) {
      text-align: left;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(3) {
      text-align: center;
    }
    thead th:nth-child(4) {
      text-align: left;
    }
    tbody td:nth-child(1) {
      text-align: right;
    }
    tbody td:nth-child(3) {
      text-align: "." center;
    }
```

However, when I employ this code within my `<td>` elements located on separate rows and contain various decimal placed numbers, the output doesn't appear to line up the periods directly beneath each other. I have the `text-aligned` to `center` to test this `.` syntax (I understand numbers should be styled to `text-align: right;`)
Am I misinterpreting the function of this syntax? Am I not doing something correctly? or does this syntax simply not work?

Comment: Can you share the complete code

Comment: Hi @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 I have uploaded the code that I am testing this syntax on.  The text-align: "." center; syntax is at the bottom of the CSS for your reference, and I'm trying to use it to place the periods within the decimals numbers of the 'costs' column, beneath each other. Thanks.